# logistic regression on a 2 cohort dataset, returns error

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, glm

I'm trying to fit a `glm model` to a dataset with `a,b,c predictors`, and a `categorical variable c` that defines one portion of the dataset as 0 and one as 1.

I'm trying to model the effects of these predictors on my binomial outcome variable with respect to which cohort variable c the data are in... 
if I use variable c as a regular predictor, I get a warning and I believe the coefficients and p values are off... the chisq ran on resid. s.e. with the df gives me a terrible goodness of fit... Help? I've searched for similar questions and I've not come up with much.

Warning message: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

```
  data :
   str(m2) 'data.frame':    452 obs. of 4 variables: 
$ d1.sys_cs : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 ... 
$ d1.data_set_category: Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1... $ d1.age : num 77 65 86 75 45 60 60 68 74 57 ... 
$ d1.race : Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","3","8",..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 ...
```

Comment: can u include sample data with what error msg u got?

Comment: error: Warning message:
glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

the sample data is a few categorical variables, and a few continues numerical variables. as well as my c cohort categorical variable which indicates which cohort a data line belongs to. I have 2 cohorts of data in one dataset, trying to model the predictors on them for my outcome variable with respect to my cohort variable... should I just dismiss the warning and accept the model as it stands?

Comment: and sample data with `str(data)`

Comment: updated: 
outcome var is sys_cs
cohort var is data_set_cat
> str(m2)
'data.frame': 452 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ d1.sys_cs           : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 ...
 $ d1.data_set_category: Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ d1.age              : num  77 65 86 75 45 60 60 68 74 57 ...
 $ d1.race             : Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","3","8",..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 ...

Comment: @saisaran does this help

Comment: u r getting warning message or error message? if error comes nothing action was happened on data but warning msg means u r getting the output but check the difference in both

Comment: Updated above: it was a warning message. I dont trust the results of the model though..

Comment: u can google the same thing ..i have checked ..based on the data also the same error will come in many cases. can u google it once

Comment: try to google the error msg and check on what parameters it is getting

Comment: It sounds like you may have this issue: https://www.researchgate.net/post/Can_anyone_help_me_with_dealing_with_perfect_separation_in_logistic_regression_in_R. For some combination of your predictors all cases fall into one or other class of your response variable?

Comment: well, yes the response variable is binary. And my cohort variable c is binary... @Cleland

Comment: If you search for the warning message on this page it explains the problem quite well. https://www.r-bloggers.com/learn-logistic-regression-and-beyond/ . You could try using a regularised logistic regression like that available in glmnet package maybe.